# Hikari: Apparent connection leak detected

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, heap-memory, hikaricp

In my Spring boot application,

```
datasource:
    oracle:
      hikari:
        jdbc-url: URL
        username: Username
        password: password
        minimum-idle: 3
        maximum-pool-size: 10
        max-lifetime: 0
        connection-test-query: select 1 from dual
        leak-detection-threshold: 10000
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        idleTimeout: 0
        keepaliveTime: 300000
```

With this config, I'm getting error:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask : Connection leak detection triggered for oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@48063c71 on thread taskExecutor-1, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
Previously reported leaked connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@48063c71 on thread taskExecutor-1 was returned to the pool (unleaked)
```

The memory usage in AppMetrix has jumped to 90% which is extremely high. Now, if I run any other job, the issue will be Heap out of memory.

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to a low value of hikari.leakDetectionThreshold property (10000 ms i.e 10 seconds). Try increasing it to 1 minute (60000 ms).

Comment: Should I change any other parameter or just leakDetectionThreshold?

Comment: changing leakDetectionThreshold parameter should be sufficient.

Comment: Does this also affect memory % usage or this fix just caters to "Apparent connection leak detected" warning?

Comment: No it doesnt. Refer https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP. 
leakDetectionThreshold
This property controls the amount of time that a connection can be out of the pool before a message is logged indicating a possible connection leak. A value of 0 means leak detection is disabled. Lowest acceptable value for enabling leak detection is 2000 (2 seconds). Default: 0